# Creating two columns of cumulative sum based on the categories of one column

Tags: r, cumulative-frequency

I like to create two columns with cumulative frequency of "A" and "B" in the assignment columns.

`df = data.frame(id = 1:10, assignment= c("B","A","B","B","B","A","B","B","A","B"))`

```
            id assignment
        1   1          B
        2   2          A
        3   3          B
        4   4          B
        5   5          B
        6   6          A
        7   7          B
        8   8          B
        9   9          A
        10 10          B
```

The resulting table would have this format

```
            id  assignment  A   B
        1   1   B           0   1
        2   2   A           1   1
        3   3   B           1   2
        4   4   B           1   3
        5   5   B           1   4
        6   6   A           2   4
        7   7   B           2   5
        8   8   B           2   6
        9   9   A           3   6
       10   10  B           3   7
```

How to generalize the codes for more than 2 categories (say for "A","B",C")?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply` over `unique` values in  `assignment` to create new columns.

```
vals <- sort(unique(df$assignment))
df[vals] <- lapply(vals, function(x) cumsum(df$assignment == x))
df

#   id assignment A B
#1   1          B 0 1
#2   2          A 1 1
#3   3          B 1 2
#4   4          B 1 3
#5   5          B 1 4
#6   6          A 2 4
#7   7          B 2 5
#8   8          B 2 6
#9   9          A 3 6
#10 10          B 3 7
```

Comment: I have the following error when running the codes "Error in Summary.factor(1:2, na.rm = FALSE) :  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors"

Comment: @user15219127 It seems you are on R < 4.0.0. Add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` creation. Use `df = data.frame(id = 1:10, assignment= c("B","A","B","B","B","A","B","B","A","B"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `model.matrix` with `colCumsums`

```
library(matrixStats)
cbind(df, colCumsums(model.matrix(~ assignment - 1, df[-1])))
```

Comment: What an amazing solution using `model.matrix`!

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
transform(
  df,
  A = cumsum(assignment == "A"),
  B = cumsum(assignment == "B")
)
```

gives

```
   id assignment A B
1   1          B 0 1
2   2          A 1 1
3   3          B 1 2
4   4          B 1 3
5   5          B 1 4
6   6          A 2 4
7   7          B 2 5
8   8          B 2 6
9   9          A 3 6
10 10          B 3 7
```